# Firebase Google linked account returns null email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Sometimes in my app, whenever I get the logged in user provider data from Firebase, the linked Google account comes empty or null.

[image]

In firebase I have linked my google accouny with the login, as you can see in the console:
[image]

In the project settings I have Multiple Accounts per email enabled.

Comment: Are you using multiple accounts per email setting?

Comment: No, should I? The email accounts are all different.

Comment: No you don't need. Just was checking. Did you try using another Google account to test this?

Comment: @bojeil It happened again today,according to the projects specifications I need to enable multiple accounts per email settings. Could this be why its happening? And yes, it happens whit all Google accounts I've tried. Even if the original account is a "non-Google" one.

Comment: will you please show the whole user object. conosle.log the logged in user and show the whole object

Comment: This is too less information to answer upon. Can you provide a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you're using to create the user.  There should be enough information that anyone can use to reliably reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Which Firebase version are you using ?

Comment: if you're using lesser than 6.2.1 then it was the issue at company side but they fix it in 6.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Did you use oAuth scopes for both user profile and **email**:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('google.com');
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
 var user = result.user;
});
```

Comment: @Irente please mark Reti's answer as the correct one if this solved it.  Note this happens "sometimes" because of provider-specific logic about missing scopes (defaulting, using historical authentication records for this user, etc.)